# NodeJs: How to export all the modules and variables in a Javascript file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I export all the modules and variables present in a Javascript file using NodeJS. Suppose i have a .js file with 20 functions and 20 variables and i need to export all of the functions and variables at once and not one by one. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You must explicitly name them, in some way.

If Amberlamps' answer is not possible (you *want* them at the base level), you could still do:

```
module.exports = {
  functionA: function () {
    // TODO
  },
  functionB: function () {
    // TODO
  },
  // the rest
};
```

Comment: What if it is an external library file and its not editable. How do i use the functions provided inside the library?

Comment: @user1999645: What do you mean? How would you export them one by one then?

Comment: You seem to mix things. A .js file used as a node module have a clear contract: fill `exports` or redefine `module.exports`. Also, if you ask how to exports things, you are the author. If you are not the author, you do are not in the business of exporting. Your "external file that is not editable" is completely different kind of beast than node module. Try to formulate your requirement more precisely - what do you really want?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
exports.MyApp = {
    functionA: function() {
        // TODO
    },
    functionB: function() {
        // TODO
    }
};
```

Comment: What if it is an external library file and its not editable. How do i use the functions provided inside the library?